# How to recognize oneTap/doubleTap at moment?

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I Know filtering oneTap/doubleTap using a Apple API. code are follows.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;


[self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];


UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

**[singleTapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTapGestureRecognizer];**

[self addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

but oneTap/doubleTap checkDelayTime is feeling a so Long (About 0.5sec?).
Generally App Users of the reaction is very fast. Although 0.5 seconds is typically short-time. but In Mobile Device Environment is long-time, because users react is very important.

Speaking to the point, YouTubeApp[image] have a very Perfectly algorithm about filtering at a moment oneTap/doubleTap. oneTap-doubleTap checkDelay is VeryVeryShort Perfectly Optimization.

oneTap(show/hidden controlBar)

doubleTap(full/default videoScreenSize)

How to implement like YoutubeApp? about oneTap-doubleTap filtering Not Using a requireGestureRecognizerToFail Selector. about very short delay oneTap-doubleTap distinguishing.

I think YoutubeApp is Not Use a requireGestureRecognizer Selector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is easiest to do without gesture recognizers. Then you can control the delay. The code below is a variation of Apple's original documentation that I use in one of my projects. I have [blog post that talks about it as well](http://blog.tyreeapps.com/2009/10/single-tap-and-double-tap-iphone.html).

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
//This will cancel the singleTap action
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if (touch.tapCount == 1) {
  //if they tapped within the coin then place the single tap action to fire after a delay of 0.3
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(coin.frame,[touch locationInView:self.view])){
    //this is the single tap action being set on a delay
  [self performSelector:@selector(onFlip) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
  }else{
   //I change the background image here
  }
 } else if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
  //this is the double tap action
  [theCoin changeCoin:coin];
 }
}
```

Comment: It's a very nice solution however I'd rather work with gesture recognizers as long as I can. You can customize the delay using my solution below with a similar approach and even less code.

Answer (score 22):

The **easiest** way to do this is to subclass **UITapGestureRecognizer** and not a general UIGestureRecognizer.

Like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

#define UISHORT_TAP_MAX_DELAY 0.2
@interface UIShortTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer

@end
```

And simply implement:

```
@implementation UIShortTapGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(UISHORT_TAP_MAX_DELAY * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        // Enough time has passed and the gesture was not recognized -> It has failed.
        if  (self.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
        {
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }
    });
}
@end
```

Comment: Would be helpful to indicate that this requires #import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

Comment: Thanks for the hint @barfoon, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great solution using recognizers - seems clunky otherwise to have taps be a special case if you have existing recognizers for other gestures.

Comment: As @Klaas pointed out, you can do something like this in didMoveToView in an SKScene subclass (if working in SpriteKit):

UIShortTapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UIShortTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

...    
[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
...

Comment: Don't use `dispatch_after` for this. As the name implies, the only guarantee is that the code executes *after* the given amount of time.   You could see touch response vary depending on the load on the system. It would be better to use a `CADisplayLink` for this. You're also capturing `self` strongly inside your block, which is likely to produce a memory leak.

Comment: @bcattle there's no leak here. The block is not retained by self, it's retained by the dispatch_after method.

Answer (score 14):

only thing you need to do is add extra line of code to use requireGestureRecognizerToFail

```
[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

then whole code become to:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(beginComicTransitions:)] autorelease];    
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;   

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bringMenu:)] autorelease];    
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;

[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

here's `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` means:

- if not recognized double tap, then single tap be recognized
- if recognized double tap, will not recognize single tap

swift version code is:

```
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTapped:")
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)
```

Comment: sorry didn't read to the end of your question ... where you said you don't want to use requireGestureRecognizer

Comment: You don't need to set `delegate = self`, you don't use the delegate

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple custom gesture recognizers for double taps where you can specify the maximum allowed time between taps. This is based on @Walters answer.

PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer.h :

```
@interface PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval maximumDoubleTapDuration;

@end
```

PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer.m :

```
#import "PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer ()
@property (nonatomic) int tapCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval startTimestamp;
@end

@implementation PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];
    if (self) {
        _maximumDoubleTapDuration = 0.3f; // assign default value
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}

- (void)reset {
    [super reset];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    self.tapCount = 0;
    self.startTimestamp = 0.f;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    if (touches.count != 1 ) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    } else {
        if (self.tapCount == 0) {
            self.startTimestamp = event.timestamp;
            [self performSelector:@selector(timeoutMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:self.maximumDoubleTapDuration];
        }
        self.tapCount++;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if (self.tapCount > 2) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    } else if (self.tapCount == 2 && event.timestamp < self.startTimestamp + self.maximumDoubleTapDuration) {
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
        NSLog(@"Recognized in %f", event.timestamp - self.startTimestamp);
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

- (void)timeoutMethod {
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

@end
```

You can use it like this:

```
PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGr = [[PbDoubleTapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_doubleTapAction)];
doubleTapGr.maximumDoubleTapDuration = 0.4;
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGr];
```

You can combine this with `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to get the behavior that was asked for.

Comment: Beware that this also recognizes TouchDownFirstFinger, TouchDownSecondFinger, TouchUpFirstFinger, TouchUpSecondFinger.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.1** version of [eladleb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415324/1333847) answer.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { [weak self] in
            if self?.state != .recognized {
                self?.state = .failed
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler answer to this problem, if you already have an action attached to the button or view. First, change the IBAction so that it includes the UIEvent (don't forget to reconnect it to your button or view in the Storyboard):

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

Next, in your you can capture the touches from the event, and then easily test for the tap count:

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

     UITouch* firstTouch = nil;
     if ((nil != ((firstTouch = event.allTouches.allObjects.firstObject)))
         && (2 == firstTouch.tapCount))
     {
         // do something for double-tap
     } else {
         // do something for single-tap
     }
}
```

You can extend this solution with other cases for different event parameters, such as long taps.

Answer (score -1):

```
@interface NaMeClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

//...code...

```
//viewDidLoad
self.singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapIcon:)];
self.singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
self.singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
self.singleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[self addGestureRecognizer:self.singleTap];

//.....code

-(void)tapIcon:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    if (tapGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        if (!self.timer) {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2
                         target:self selector:@selector(singleTap) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }else{
            [self doubleTap];
     }
}
```

}

```
-(void)singleTap{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    NSLog(@"1111111111111");
}

-(void)doubleTap{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    NSLog(@"22222222222");
}
```