# UIGesture recognizer, differentiate between single and double tap.

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, xcode4.5

I am adding two gesture recognizers to a view with the code below. What I want is: if the user taps once one thing happens. If they tap twice another thing happens.

As it is, the single tap action occurs whether the user taps once or twice. In other words when I double tap I get two actions, instead of one as I would prefer

differentiate

```
//gesture recognizer.
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizerShowHideMenu = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doOneThing)];
[tapRecognizerShowHideMenu setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizerShowHideMenu setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizerShowHideMenu];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizerEditEffect = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doAnotherThing)];
[tapRecognizerEditEffect setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizerEditEffect setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizerEditEffect];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
[tapRecognizerShowHideMenu requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapRecognizerEditEffect];
```

When you set requireGestureRecognizerToFail: for a gesture recognizer, you're saying that it should only recognize the gesture if the other gesture recognizer did not. So here, you tell the single tap to be recognized only when the double tap was not.

Comment: But in this case i think we should change the parameters

Comment: Maybe, but there's nothing wrong with having both gesture recognizers work this way if the app is intuitive and easy to use. It depends on what the asker's app does.

Comment: That certainly works Thanks. Oddly it introduced a very noticeable delay (like .25 of sec).

Comment: That's the time it takes the double-tap gesture recognizer to fail. It's waiting a moment to see if the second tap is coming.

Comment: Here's another way to implement tap and double tap without the pause, it's a little more advanced and doesn't use gesture recognizers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051627/how-to-recognize-onetap-doubletap-at-moment

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link could be helpful to you, you can do it by either Overriding Touch Event Handlers, or use Gesture Recognizers.

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/06/14/differentiating-tap-counts-on-ios/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work pretty well, modified from the link given by Anton in a comment above.

[How to recognize oneTap/doubleTap at moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051627/how-to-recognize-onetap-doubletap-at-moment)

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.tapCount == 1) {

        [self performSelector:@selector(showHideMenu) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.15];

    } else if (touch.tapCount == 2) {

        [self performSelector:@selector(editEffect) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be more useful to use long tap gesture recognizer instead of double tap gesture recognizer. And then you won't have such conflicts