# Swift: Delay for Double-Tap in touchesBegan / touchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, delay

Does anyone know the Swift equivalent for the below Objective-C code?

I am trying to work out the best-practice way to implement double-taps in a SpriteKit game, which requires a delay on the single tap first. UIGestureRecognizers seem to cause too much delay for the single-tap, and whilst the below was suggested as a solution for [this Obj-C question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051627/how-to-recognize-onetap-doubletap-at-moment), I can't seem to find a Swift atlernative.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(singleTap) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
dispatch_after(0.3, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
  self.singleTap()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try this, I'm getting the following error. Any idea why?
TileSprite.swift:51:13: Type 'dispatch_time_t' does not conform to protocol 'FloatLiteralConvertible'